# i am not getting whatsapp, telegram icon in react-share-social npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-share

I am building an application in which we can share post on social media too. I am using `react-share-social`. `"facebook"`, `"twitter"`, `"linkedin"` and a few icons are displaying but `"whatsapp"` and `"telegram"` icons are not displaying on web page. I tried just same as npm `react-share-social` documentation.

```
<div style={{ marginTop: "-20px", marginBottom: "15px" }}>
  <ShareSocial
    url={process.browser && window.location.href}
    socialTypes={[
      "facebook",
      "whatsapp",
      "twitter",
      "linkedin",
      "pinterest",
      "instapaper",
      "line",
      "viber",
      "Telegram",
      "mailru"
    ]}
    style={{
      height: "200px",
      // overflow: "hidden",
      background: "none",
    }}
  />
</div>
```

output is:

[image]

npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share-social

Comment: Any errors/warnings in the browser console? Can you try lowercase telegram?

Comment: no there is no any warning

Comment: yes i tried lowercase and uppercase camelcase etc all style but not displaying

Comment: Try with just `socialTypes={[ "whatsapp", "Telegram"]}` and also try with another browser.

Comment: yes i have also tried just   socialTypes={["whatsapp", "Telegram"]}  but these are not displaying other icons are displaying properly

Comment: There doesn't appear to be much to this library, perhaps file an issue in the repo? Are there any errors in the console or any dev tools? Have you inspected the DOM to see what *was* rendered there?

Comment: Can you inspect the item and check if the element exists?

Comment: i am using whatsapp and telegram icon on my code editor but when i inspect they don't appear on dom and there is no any warning.

Comment: can anyone suggest any other social share icon for react js application ?

Comment: Stick to 'telegram' (lowercase) as the 'Telegram' throws an error. Also, I cannot reproduce your error. All works fine on my setup.